# What are the grammatical similarities between Mongolian and Japanese?

Tags: grammar

I am not claiming any Altaic theory or any other linguistic hypothesis so please do not mention that in the answers.

I am just a native English-speaker with a Mongolian background trying to learn, so any tips from Japanese-speakers or learners of the language would be helpful.

Any links to published studies would be most helpful as well, thank you.

Comment: I'm confused.  You're asking us to explain the grammatical similarities, but you're saying don't resort to Altaic theory or any other linguistic hypothesis?  Kind of sounds like an impossible question to answer.  What exactly are you looking for that would lie outside of linguistics?  This question seems inherently linguistic in nature.

Comment: @A.Ellett Assuming that Japonic and Mongolic are not related (in linguistic sense), there could still be some borrowings or accidental similarities... Possibly this question would be more suitable for https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: There was hypothesis of Alexander Vovin that Old Japanese *ki(\*2)saraŋgi* (> *kisaragi*) "second lunar month" is a possible borrowing from Mongolic, related to Mongolian *qoyar* "two" and *saran* "moon, month". (Alexander Vovin, 1993, 「Japanese kisaragi “second lunar month”.」 Eurasian Yearbook 65: 116)

Comment: I'm not familiar with this area of study. Anecdotally, years ago while living in Japan, I spoke with a Japanese woman who spent a couple years in Mongolia for work. She found Mongolian much easier to learn than English, partly due to structural similarities -- the order of concepts was a closer match, as compared to English and Japanese that are sometimes backwards from each other. Separately, Academia.edu might be a good place to explore. You need to create an account, but it's free. Here's one potential starting point: https://www.academia.edu/search?q=japanese%20mongolian